# How fast do they spin astronauts these days? Maximum routine g-training for astronauts in the 21st century?

Tags: astronauts, medical, training

[Comments](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/27339/what-is-beco-gemini-same-as-meco?noredirect=1#comment104093_27339) got me thinking about [NASA's 20 g centrifuge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:20G_centrifuge.jpg). Gemini astronauts pushed to 7 or perhaps 8 g's as discussed in [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/27318/12102) but these days with nicely throttleable engines astronauts going to space experience no more than ballpark 3 g under normal conditions.

- [Puzzler: What acceleration are these astronauts experiencing?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21173/12102)
- [Has an object ever been put in orbit where the first stage was always at maximum thrust?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27312/12102)

The NASA [**20 G** Centrifuge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:20G_centrifuge.jpg) (also [NASA page](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/ames/multimedia/images/2006/20gcentrifuge.html)) potentially goes up to 20 g, but I'm guessing they don't do that so much any more.

**Question:** How fast (to what g-level) do they spin astronauts these days? Maximum routine g-training for astronauts in the 21st century?

[image]

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:20G_centrifuge.jpg)

Comment: Tim Peake flew to the ISS in late 2015.  There is a video of him experiencing 8g in a centrifuge here:  https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/av/science-environment-35030406/tim-peake-experiences-huge-g-forces-in-a-centrifuge  In a normal launch the force of a soyuz is less than 4g, but an emergency might subject the crew to higher than that

Comment: This 20 g centrifuge was never used to expose astronauts to 20 g. According to this NASA [page](https://science.nasa.gov/science-news/science-at-nasa/2003/07feb_stronggravity/) "additional safety features permit human studies from 1 to 12.5-g"

Comment: From [The Pull of HyperGravity](https://science.nasa.gov/science-news/science-at-nasa/2003/07feb_stronggravity/) "To produce a centrifugal force of 2-g, the centrifuge spins about 15 revolutions a minute."

To reach 20 g the centrifuge should spin a 100 times faster, 25 revolutions per second. For 4 g 1 revolution per second, for 5 g 1.5625 revolutions per second.

Comment: @Uwe  $\sqrt{10}$ times faster!!  $F_C = m v^2/r$

Comment: @uhoh square root of 10 instead of square of 10 is much better. So only 47.4 revolutions a minute for 20 g. I stand corrected.

Comment: Is it training or only a test? To get a training effect, about 2 to 4 repetitions per week should be done for at least a month or two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only centrifuge training received by Shuttle astronauts was a 3g ride in the Brooks Air Force Base facility as new astronauts, followed by optional use of the facility to verify ascent/entry suit fitting.

Description by Clay Anderson from [here](https://www.quora.com/In-astronaut-training-astronauts-ride-on-a-huge-centrifuge-to-make-them-experience-high-accelerations-Is-this-only-to-test-how-their-bodies-react-to-such-large-g-forces-In-other-words-does-actual-spaceflight-also-produce-motion-sickness)

> Shuttle training sent us to a San Antonio Air Force Base for a single
>   ride in their centrifuge.   The Shuttle's ascent and entry profiles
>   were flown, to give us the exposure to what 2-3 g's would feel like. 
>   Actually no big deal, and just "checking a box."

Brooks AFB closed in 2011.

Anderson goes on to comment about Soyuz centrifuge training:

> In Russia I flew their centrifuge as well.  Since I was a ShREC
>   (Shuttle Rotating Expedition Crew Member), I only did the Soyuz
>   re-entry centrifuge profile, in a manner similar to that of the
>   shuttle, pulling the requisite number of g's at the appropriate times.
>   However, we also did some separate runs, which reflected a ballistic
>   Soyuz re-entry profile.  This re-entry, a contingency; is extremely
>   dynamic.  We pulled 8 and 10 g's for short periods of time, reflecting
>   what would be experienced in the event of a failure driving us into
>   that mode.

[image]
(excerpt from Shuttle Crew Training Catalog)