# Experiments during ascent

Tags: launch, astronauts, experiment

Has any astronaut or cosmonaut personally performed experiments, that could only be done by a human in flight, during the ascent phase of a flight.  If so, what kind of experiment(s) did they perform?

Comment: I think this question is a bit too broad.  The ultimate answer is "yes" in the sense that just about every crewed launch is still experimental (as the recent Soyuz failure has taught us, even after some 60 years launches can and do still go awry).

Comment: Are you asking about *experiments performed during the ascent phase* of a flight?

Comment: One example might be these swinging objects present in many (most?) Soyuz launches, but we'd need more evidence that a proper experiment was done. [Puzzler: What acceleration are these astronauts experiencing?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21173/12102)

Comment: Follow-up question, based on uhoh's example: https://space.stackexchange.com/q/37815/26446

Comment: Aren't sounding rockets fitted for such experiments? (no need to go to orbit to make an experience during launch)

Comment: Edited the question to clarify why sounding rockets would not fit what I was hoping to learn about such experiments.

Comment: Ascents don't last very long and if you're piloting or monitoring the ship, you are not going to be  doing experiments. For the US, that pretty much limits any possible source of such experiments to Space Shuttle middeck crewmembers.  I don't know of any official investigations done by these crewmembers.